# ScalaTest Spec Compilation Error

Tags: scala, testing, dependencies

I am new to Scala and I am trying to use [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/).  I included its dependency in my build.sbt file as 
`libraryDependencies++=Seq(
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.1.7" % "test"
)`

and refreshed sbt and now it appears in my External Libraries folder so I think it was installed correctly.  Now I want to make a test class.  So I created one under src/test/scala.  I used the example from the ScalaTest website's frontpage which is

```
import collection.mutable.Stack
import org.scalatest._

class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "A Stack" should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {
    val stack = new Stack[Int]
    stack.push(1)
    stack.push(2)
    stack.pop() should be (2)
    stack.pop() should be (1)
  }

  it should "throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped" in {
    val emptyStack = new Stack[Int]
    a [NoSuchElementException] should be thrownBy {
      emptyStack.pop()
    }
  }
}
```

However when I run this class I get the error

```
 Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to type compileTimeOnly
in package scala.annotation which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling package.class.
```

and also

```
 Error:(4, 27) Reference to class FlatSpec in package scalatest should not have survived past type checking,
it should have been processed and eliminated during expansion of an enclosing macro.
class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
                      ^
```

Could someone tell me what the problem is.  It looks like it is not recognizing ScalaTest.  However it is in my External Libraries and IntelliJ's auto-complete also shows that it is there.  Do I somehow need to refresh something else before I can actually start using ScalaTest?

EDIT:

Also when I run `test:compile` from sbt I get

```
  [error] error while loading package, class file needed by package is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] error while loading Matchers, class file needed by Matchers is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] error while loading Assertions, class file needed by Assertions is missing.
[error] reference value internal of package scala.reflect.macros refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] error while loading AbstractSuite, class file needed by AbstractSuite is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] error while loading Tolerance, class file needed by Tolerance is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] error while loading BeWord, class file needed by BeWord is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] error while loading ResultOfNotWordForAny, class file needed by ResultOfNotWordForAny is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] error while loading NotWord, class file needed by NotWord is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] 8 errors found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
```

Comment: have you tried `;reload; clean; test:compile` ?

Comment: I just included the errors from `test:compile`.  It looks like ScalaTest is not installed correctly...

Comment: to auto-match the scalaVersion (I suppose you use 2.11.x) you better write `libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.7" % "test")`

Comment: That creates an unresolved dependency.  `
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.9.2;2.1.7: not found
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 31-May-2014 7:06:20 PM
`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does sbt say "bad symbolic reference..." for test with ScalaTest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472645/why-does-sbt-say-bad-symbolic-reference-for-test-with-scalatest)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems SBT tries to compile against scala 2.9.2.
I guess you have to add one of

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
```

or

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
```

to your `build.sbt`

and of course

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.7" % "test"
```

Additionally you can try the latest [SBT launcher](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html).

Comment: Adding `scalaVersion := "2.11.1"` seems to have worked in that the tests run from inside IntelliJ.  However, when I run `test:compile`, it still creates an error `[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.1. Compiling... [error] (compile:compile) Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface'

`  So, I'll accept your answer but could you guess why this error is occurring?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think Scala 2.11 requires a newer SBT version. The IDEA Scala plugin is bundled with it's own launcher. Try my mentioned link and the SBT documentation about this.

Comment: This fixed my problem too (adding `scalaVersion := "2.11.2"` to build.sbt). Neither the error message nor the fix is very clear though. I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to compile with scala `2.9` then updated `JAVA_HOME` and `IDEA_JDK` to point to `jdk1.7` instead of `jdk1.8`