# spark streaming + kafka sbt compilation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, sbt, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have an example with spark streaming + kafka. It works well from IDE. but when I try to compile it by SBT from console, like **sbt compile**. Have got an error.

The Main class:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))

  val kafkaStream1 = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("t1" -> 5))
  //val kafkaStream2 = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("topic2" -> 5))

  //kafkaStream.fla
  kafkaStream1.print()
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
```

error message:

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to type compileTimeOnly
[error] in package scala.annotation which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling package.class.
Reference to method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef should not have survived past type checking,
[error] it should have been processed and eliminated during expansion of an enclosing macro.
[error]   val kafkaStream1 = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("t1" -> 5))
[error]                                                                                                           ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

sbt:

```
    name := "test"
    val sparkVersion = "2.0.0"

    lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
      organization := "com.test",
      version := "1.0",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
      test in assembly := {}
    )    
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11" % sparkVersion
)
```

Do you have ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: This may give some clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472645/why-does-sbt-say-bad-symbolic-reference-for-test-with-scalatest

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your build.sbt. One of the reason that could cause "bad symbolic reference" issue is scala version mismatch. Take a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472645/why-does-sbt-say-bad-symbolic-reference-for-test-with-scalatest) for more details on that issue .Also make sure that Scala version that your using is same as that is expected by spark, take a look at [this blog post](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2016/01/problem-with-scala-version-mismatch-in.html) for more details

Comment: Should I use scala 2.10 ?

Comment: It depends on the version of Spark your using for example Spark 1.3.1 uses Scala 2.10.4, but Spark 2.0 uses Scala 2.11.*, Take a look at the documentation for the version of Spark your using

Comment: it is really strange. I use spark 2.0.0 and scala 2.11.8. Updated build.sbt used this manual http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html. In the IDE works, but from command line "sbt compile" have the same error...