# facing error in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

i am trying to run a simple ScalaTest app to understand the scala testing
my code is:

```
 package org.scalatest.examples.flatspec
 import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
 import collection.mutable.Stack
 import org.scalatest._
 class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
 "A Stack" should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {
  val stack = new Stack[Int]
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.pop() should be (2)
stack.pop() should be (1)
}

it should "throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped" in {
val emptyStack = new Stack[Int]
a [NoSuchElementException] should be thrownBy {
  emptyStack.pop()
} 
}
}
```

i have also downloaded scalatest_2.11-2.2.4.jar. i am compiling the file using command

```
 scalac -cp scalatest_2.11-2.2.4.jar ExampleSpec.scala
```

and facing the following error

```
 error while loading package, class file needed by package is missing.
 reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974896/scalatest-spec-compilation-error

Comment: the error arises when you compile? I don't have that error when compiling. Provide scalac -version

Comment: got the answer. actually i was using scala 2.9 version now i updated it to 2.10 then their is no compilation error. thanx

Comment: @nikiforo i while i am trying to execute following error occurred and system stuck after that
           An exception or error caused a run to abort. This may have been caused by a problematic custom reporter.
           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    scala.runtime.ObjectRef.create(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/runtime/Obje  ctRef;
 at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2347)
 at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter